# C# - Using nullable types as parameters

Tags: c#, .net, performance, garbage-collection

Can anyone tell me if it is a good idea to accept nullable parameters for a function and then setting the parameter to null after using it?  Would this be a good programming practice to free up unused resources? Ex:

```
public static bool SendEmail(MailAddressCollection? To, string Subject, string Body)
{
    // use the values stored in To, Subject, and Body to send the message.
    To = null;
}
```

Comment: 1) `string?` isn't a valid type. 2) The GC takes care of that for you.

Comment: Do not worrie about that, Garbage Collector will take care of that.
More information about GC http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I didn't mean string necessarily.  I just used the function I wrote as an example as to what I meant.

Comment: I would rather use optinal parameters http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx
SendEmail(string subject="default subject", string body="default body)

Comment: And unless the parameters are `ref`, whatever code *called* your method will (usually) still be holding a copy of all of the references, so nothing is newly unreachable by setting *your* variables to `null`.

Comment: I've just noticed that `To` in your example must be of type `Nullable<MailAddressCollection>` where `MailAddressCollection` must be a `struct`. So, `To` is a value type. If so, `To` is not subject to `GC` unless you box it somewhere. Next, assigning `null` to `To` is *not* a reference assignment, but the assignment of a default value of `Nullable<MailAddressCollection>`. Therefore, you should not think about `GC` because `To` value lives on the stack and is destroyed as soon as the method ends (or earlier if jitter decides so).

Comment: On the other hand, since `To` is of value type, it gets copied by each assignment. So, you cannot know how many copies of `To` value exists in memory. If the size of `MailAddressCollection` is somewhat big, you should convert it into a `class`. The general advice is to only use a `struct` if its size is less than 16 bytes ([check out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx))

Comment: MailAddressCollection is referring to the System.Net.Mail.MailAddressCollection class, not a struct.

Answer (score 4):

**No**, it's not a good idea. What you're doing has no practical impact. **The only variable you're setting to null is a local one** for the method. That variable will go out of scope automatically anyway.

On the contrary, if you got that object as an argument, it means that **there's a reference to that object outside of the current method anyway** and you're not affecting that reference. So you're not helping the GC at all by doing anything inside the method as it is. The only way to have any non-local effect in this regard would be to pass all your arguments as `ref` and thus be able to set the passed variables to null. However, this would be *absolutely horrible* because every innocent looking method call could potentially ruin references that are assumed not-null later on.

Generally, what you should do in most applications is not think about it. The GC is a lot better at detecting the unused memory, because it can examine the stack for references and it has access to relevant metadata emitted by the JIT compiler that you don't get to see.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not. You've got a GC to take care of that for you. You're not in an unmanaged language, you don't need to dispose resources (unless they're `IDisposable`, of course).

Comment: I've updated my code to more accurately represent my question.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is a bad practice in managed environment such as .NET. 
Garbage collector in .NET can automatically collect objects with no references and free memory from them.

But there are rare exceptions. You can manually set reference to null and explicitly call GC:

```
public static void ForceGC(ref object obj) {        
    obj = null;
    GC.Collect();
}
```

Comment: This method of forcing an object collection is useless. First, if you null one reference to an object, it does *not* mean there are no more references from anywhere else (e.g. a caller of the immediate caller method), so there's no guarantee the object will be collected. Second, calling GC.Collect in order to collect one object is the straight road to massive performance issues because garbage collection always inspects *all* objects and hence is expensive. The general advice is to avoid forced GC whenever.